# fooTable not working properly in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, footable

I am having issue with **fooTable** in **AngularJS** ,here is what i am doing:

```
<table class="table m-b-none" ui-jq="footable" data-filter="#filter" data-page-size="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-toggle="true">Name</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Logo</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Website</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet" data-name="Friendly URL">URL</th>
            <th data-hide="all">External Parameter 1</th>
            <th data-hide="all">External Parameter 2</th>
            <th data-hide="all">Meta Keywords</th>
            <th data-hide="all">Meta Description</th>
            <th data-hide="all">Period</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="store in stores">
            <td>{{store.name}}</td>
            <td><img ng-src="{{store.logo}}" /></td>
            <td>{{store.website}}</td>
            <td>{{store.friendly_url}}</td>
            <td>{{store.external_parameter1}}</td>
            <td>{{store.external_parameter2}}</td>
            <td>{{store.meta_keywords}}</td>
            <td>{{store.meta_description}}</td>
            <td>{{store.period}}</td>
            <td data-value="1">
                <!--Edit Button-->
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ui-sref="app.store.edit({editId: store.id})">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </a>
                <!--Delete Button-->
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-click="deleteStore(store.id)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination"></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

When i **refresh** the page by pressing `F5` the output is as it should be:

[image]

then after i click somewhere else `e.g. Add Store` and come back to this page, now the picture changes:

[image]

the **+** icon gone, and all `<td>` are showing, they are not getting hide, as it should be.

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('storesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.stores = {};
    $http.get("http://MyApiUrl/store.php").
    success(function(data){
        $scope.stores = data;
        //$('.table').trigger('footable_redraw');
    });
}]);
```

I also tried using **`$('.table').trigger('footable_redraw');`** but no luck.

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
success(function(data){
    $scope.stores = data;
    $timeout(function(){
        $('.table').trigger('footable_redraw');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: 'footable_redraw' was what I was looking for. Thanks.